# What is foundational to a study of Jackson's EM?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a chemistry graduate student on a course of self-study through some of the legends of physics pedagogy. My goal is to graduate to a level which would allow me to absorb and work exercises from the legendary *J.D. Jackson*'s **Classical Electrodynamics**.

This may sound subjective, but I believe this can be answered (not just discussed) in terms of the specific mathematical & physics background one would need to approach the text. Specific materials are appreciated, but fields of study and mathematical domains of knowledge would be more objective, such as:

- Differential/Integral Vector Calculus & Gradients over real fields
- Differential Equations, PDEs, solving & boundary problems in Cartesian/Spherical/Ellipisoidal
- Groups, Rings & Fields
- Proof writing, elementary sets

Comment: The last two items are definitely overkill.

Comment: Zero is right, in my opinion, personally I have never seen the last two  on the stuff I have read in relation to your post but maybe include resources recommened, but there could be a duplicate here. There is a free e book, ....Mary Boas, Mathematical Methods For Physics  pdf, ........if you don't have it already I would recommend it for  a Google search.